# VBA project need help to debug one row

Tags: excel, vba

Hi All a piece of my code below throws an error if there I only one row found as out put. **If it is working on more than one row it works fine though.**

**I have only included the naughty section of the macro**

**MyCode:**

```
Dim LZ As Long

LZ = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Find("*", SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, SearchOrder:=xlByRows).Row
Range("AM2").AutoFill Destination:=Range("AM2:AM" & LZ)
```

Comment: `if ActiveSheet.UsedRange.rows.count=2 then lz=2 else...` why not use `usedrange.rows.count`?

Comment: And please, avoid using ActiveSheet (and Select too). It's prone to error. https://www.thespreadsheetguru.com/blog/vba-guide-to-referencing-excel-worksheet-tabs

Comment: You have to be careful when using `.Find` to find the last row. You may want to see [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11169445/error-in-finding-last-used-cell-in-vba/11169920#11169920)

Comment: @TimStack: No need to go that faaar... Checkout something from [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba) ;)

Comment: Nothing wrong with some external sources